# How to know what usernames are valid in Vps?

Tags: 16.04, server, vps

I can login as root@ipaddress in vps but using a username doest not accept my password says 'Permission denied, please try again.'. How do I know valid username to use? My server OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

The tool on Ubuntu for connecting to a remote system using SSH is `ssh`.

The basic form of the command is:

```
ssh remote_host
```

The remote_host is the `IP address` or `domain name`

This command assumes that `your username` on the remote system `is the same as your username` on your local system.

If your username is different on the remote system, you can specify it:

```
ssh remote_username@remote_host
```

Once you have connected to the server, you will probably be asked to verify your identity by providing a password.

By default, Ubuntu doesn't allow the root account to do ssh.

Enabling the root account to access ssh directly is a major security risk.